# Stuck in calculating complex line integral.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I have to calculate the following line integral :

1. $\int\limits_\gamma \frac{\sin{z}}{z+i} dz\space\space\space\gamma\colon[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\space\space\space\gamma (z)=2e^{it}$

---

My calculation

1. $\int\limits_\gamma \frac{\sin{z}}{z+i} dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin 2e^{it}}{2e^{it}+i}2ie^{it}dt $

Now substitute. $z:=2e^{it}$ with $\frac{dz}{dt}=2ie^{it}\iff dt=\frac{dz}{2ie^{it}}$

It follows:  $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin{z}}{z+i}dz\space $. Now here is the part where I get stuck. I can't find an antiderivative. Is my substitution correct ?

I would appreciate any help

Solution with mathematica: $\frac{(e^2-1)\pi}{e}$

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy integral formula?

Comment: We have proven it recently. But I don't know how to apply it .

Comment: Note that your integral is $$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = 2} \frac{\sin z}{z - (-i)}\,dz.$$ Can you see the integral formula in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:

> The function $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z+i}$ has a pole at $z=-i$ since $\sin(-i)\neq 0$.

Step 2:

> Because $-i$ is surrounded by $\gamma$  the value of your integral, using Cauchy integral formula, is $$\int_\gamma f(z)~dz=2\pi i\cdot res_{-i}(f)$$ where $res_{-i}(f)$ is the residual of $f$ at $-i$, which is the coefficent of $\frac1{z+i}$ in the Laurent series of $f$ at $-i$.

Step 3:

> Let be $\sin^{(k)}$ the $k$-th derivative of $\sin$, then $\sin(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin^{(k)}(-i)}{k!}(z+i)^k$.

Step 4:

> The Laurent series of $f$ is $f(z)=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin^{(k)}(-i)}{k!}(z+i)^k}{z+i}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin^{(k)}(-i)}{k!}(z-i)^{k-1}$.

Step 5:

> Your residual of $f$ at $-i$ is $res_{-i}(f)=\sin(-i)=-\frac12(e-e^{-1})i=-\frac12\cdot\frac{e^2-1}{e}i$.

Result:

> You get $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)~dz=2\pi i\cdot res_{-i}(f)=-2\pi i\cdot \frac12\cdot\frac{e^2-1}{e}i=\frac{e^2-1}{e}\pi.$$